# How can you know the order of callback returns in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

Here is some code from a popular slide deck authored by Domenic Denicola on asynchronous programming in JavaScript.

```
function parallel(actions, callback) {
  var results = [];
  function finished(result) {
    results.push(result);
    if (results.length === actions.length) {
      callback(results);
    }
  }

  actions.forEach(function (action) {
    action(finished);
  });
}

parallel([
  function (cb) {
    twitter.getTweetsFor("domenicdenicola", cb);
  },
  function (cb) {
    stackOverflow.getAnswersFor("Domenic", cb);
  },
  function (cb) {
    fourSquare.getCheckinsFor("Domenic", cb);
  }
], function (results) {
  console.log("tweets = ", results[0]);
  console.log("answers = ", results[1]);
  console.log("checkins = ", results[2]);
});
```

If the functions in the action array work asynchronously, how can you know the order of the values in the results array?

Comment: Popularity does not imply correctness :-(

Comment: well that's not the only problem with this code.  however, in his defense, it looks like he's using this on his way to present a better solution.

Comment: I know this is about the code above, however you could use a promise library like Q.js to ensure sequence: http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/#tutorial/sequences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can you know the order of the values in the results array?

You've figured it out, one cannot know them. It would need to be

```
function parallel(actions, callback) {
  var results = [],
      cnt = actions.length;
  actions.forEach(function(action, i) {
    action(function(result) {
      results[i] = result;
      if (!--cnt)
        callback(results);
    });
  });
  if (!cnt)
    callback(results);
}
```